# EGOTableViewPullRefresh - Simulate a pull down on viewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using [EGOTableViewPullRefresh](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTableViewPullRefresh) for atable view in my app and it works great.  However I would like to be able to have the pull down effect happen on the viewDidAppear for the first load of the screen.

Is there an easy way to simulate the user scrolling the UITableView or to force EGOTableViewPullRefresh to show itself?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should accomplish what you want, it adds an inset then tells EGO that scrolling just completed.  EGO will remove the inset when its finished.

```
myUITableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(66.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidEndDragging: myUITableView];
```

Comment: This answer no longer seems to be valid.